# Dispose slow on very big filestreams?

Tags: c#, file-io

I've got this code

```
string archiveFileName = BuildArchiveFileName(i, null);
string tmpArchiveFileName = BuildArchiveFileName(i, "tmp");
try
{
    using (FileStream tmpArchiveMemoryStream = new FileStream(tmpArchiveFileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter pakWriter = new BinaryWriter(tmpArchiveMemoryStream))
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                WriteHeader(pakWriter, pakInfo.Header);
                WriteFileInfo(pakWriter, pakInfo.FileList);
                uint remainingBytesToDataOffset = pakInfo.Header.DataSectionOffset - CalculateHeaderBlockSize(pakInfo.Header);
                pakWriter.Write(Util.CreatePaddingByteArray((int)remainingBytesToDataOffset));
            }

            foreach (String file in pakInfo.FileList.Keys)
            {
                DosPak.Model.FileInfo info = pakInfo.FileList[file];
                if (info.IndexArchiveFile == i)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Writing " + file);
                    byte[] fileData = GetFileAsStream(file, false);
                    int paddingSize = (int)CalculateFullByteBlockSize((uint)fileData.Length) - fileData.Length;
                    pakWriter.Write(fileData);
                    pakWriter.Write(Util.CreatePaddingByteArray(paddingSize));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(archiveFileName);
    File.Move(tmpArchiveFileName, archiveFileName);
}
```

I've tested this with NUnit on small file sizes and it works perfectly.  Then when I tried it on a real life example , that are files over 1 GB.  I get in trouble on the delete.  It states the file is still in use by another process.  While it shouldn't that file should have been disposed of after exiting the using branch.  So I'm wondering if the dispose of the filestream is slow to execute and that is the reason I'm getting in trouble.  Small note in all my file handling I use a FileStream with the using keyword.

Comment: What happens if you call explicitly Flush on BinaryWriter and after that on FileStream?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, I'll give it a shot for now I kinda fixed it by putting System.GC.Collect(); before the File.Delete ... but implicitly calling Garbadge collection is so dirty ... I rather not keep this as a sollution :(

Comment: Flushing didn't have any effect since it isn't the Writer that is blocked.  GetFileAsStream(file, false); also has a using block in it reading from the file that is getting replaced, I'm betting he is the culprit, but thing is that using block should have disposed each time of the file access so aaaargh why is it staying open.  I'll try the Replace method , does that one block until the file can be accessed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While it shouldn't that file should have been disposed of after exiting the using branch

That's not what it is complaining about, you can't delete *archiveFileName*.  Some other process has the file opened, just as the exception message says.  If you have no idea what process that might be then start killing them off one-by-one with Task Manager's Processes tab.  That being your own process is not entirely unusual btw.  Best way is with SysInternals' Handle utility, it can show you the process name.

Deleting files is in general a perilous adventure on a multi-tasking operating system, always non-zero odds that some other process is interested in the file as well.  They ought to open the file with FileShare.Delete but that's often overlooked.

The safest way to do this is with [File.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The 3rd argument, the backup filename, is crucial, it allows the file to be renamed and continue to exist so that other process can continue to use it.  You should try to delete that backup file at the *start* of your code.  If that doesn't succeed then File.Replace() cannot work either.  But do check that it isn't a bug in your program first, run the Handle utility.

Comment: The File.Replace() method was the solution indeed.  My first attempt to fix it was to call System.GC.Collect(); before my delete and move.  That actually worked ... but that's way to dirty.  So I didn't know about Replace() (I'm a java dev, .NET is a hobby)  It seems Replace() does something to wait until it has access to the file it should replace.  Anyhow thanks for this elaborate explaination.

Comment: Hmm, you are ignoring a bug in your code.  File.Replace() can postpone having to deal with that bug, it can't fix it.

Comment: Well that was my first guess as well I have a bug with a filepointer not closing.  But ALL my file handling code is in using blocks.  There isn't one place in the code I'm keeping a stream open ... so that's what confuses me.  Now if you have some spare time and like to figure this out as well my codebase is at: https://github.com/Celludriel/DosPak

Comment: Note that sometimes antivirus programs and the like keep files locked for a short time. This may lead to a timing issue where the larger file cannot be deleted right away, but just waiting for the GC to run leaves enough time for the file to become unlocked. So it may not be your process which is at fault here; maybe catch the error upon deletion, wait for a few milliseconds, and try deleting again. It's a hack, but it can help deal with situations where "someone else" out of your control is locking your stuff.

Comment: Anti-malware typically is fairly indistinguishable from the problem they are trying to address but at least they don't get FileShare.Delete wrong.  The File.Move() call will fail, not the File.Delete call.

Comment: Somewhere in a piece of util code I got from the net was filehandling going on outside the using() block and that was the culprit of the bug.  Still it's better to use Replace() then Move() , Delete() I believe